# How to compare 4 different normal random distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I am performing a study on individuals heights, comparing 4 different areas of my city. I want to calculate the probability of each of the 4 Areas being the tallest:

- Example: What is the probability of A1 being the tallest Area ?

All of the 4 areas have a normal distribution on their heights

> Areas = A1, A2, A3, A4
>
> A1 = Mean 180 with SD 7.2
> A2 = Mean 178 with SD 7
> A3 = Mean 176 with SD 9
> A4 = Mean 182 with SD 8.4

I don't know now, how to go forward from here. I do know how to compare two Areas I saw an example [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/random-variables-ap/combining-random-variables/v/analyzing-the-difference-in-distributions):

For example, if I wanted to know the probability of A1 being taller than A2, I would get the Normal distribution of the difference of $A1-A2$, like:

$$D = A1 - A2 = 180 - 178 = 2\quad\text{ ----- this for the mean}$$

And for the SD, I get $(7.2^2 + 7^2)^{0.5} = 10.041$

So using the distribution D with mean 2 and SD 10.041, I just calculate the cumulative distribution for D>0.
But, how to do the same analysis for the 4 areas?

$$A1 > (A2\ \&\ A3\ \&\ A4)$$

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain what "being the tallest" means?  Under your model assumptions, there is no such thing as a tallest person in any of the groups; moreover, when you are given "a" random person, you have one person: to whom are they being compared??

Comment: @whuber - I want to know what is the probability of any of the areas is the highest. Similar to this question khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/random-variables-ap/… but in my case I have 4 distributions.
I have edited the question, I hope its more clear now and can be reopen. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set a threshold to decide what probability is enough to declare a winner. Say you fix this to 0.5, then an area $A_i$ is "taller" than $A_j$ if $P(A_i>A_j) > 0.5$.

You just do a pair-wise comparison (in your case 3 pairs) and keep the tallest at each step.

Comment: The question is unanswerable until a *prior* distribution for the four areas is provided.  Therefore your reply cannot be correct.  Note, too, that the question appears to be asking about the *mean* heights per area, not individual heights.

Comment: @whuber, can I assume from your comment that "the prior distribution for the fours areas"  is a combination for the individual distributions ? And, as the areas are all normal distributed, doesn't this mean that the distribution that combines the fours is also normal ? And, assuming  I have that distribution, how do I proceed ? Thank you

Comment: None of that is correct.  The combination is a *mixture,* which will not be Normal.  The general method of proceeding requires a Bayesian analysis.

Comment: @whuber Of course this can be made more rigorous, but for this specific case I dont see why this simple solution is wrong (or better, why the question in unanswerable) since the sum of two normally distributed and independent random variables is normally distributed.

Comment: The question is unanswerable because there cannot even be a probability until a prior is specified.

Comment: or implicitly assumed to be uniform

Comment: @whuber - thank you for your answer. You already said we need a prior and Bayesian analysis is the way to go on your opinion. Would it be possible for you to point me an example or some reference that I can use for study and reference ?